# Default connection pool for tomcat in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tomcat, spring-boot

What is the default value used for maximum connections on a `postgres` database with `tomcat` connection pooling using `spring-boot`?

There is a property `spring.datasource.maxActive`, but when I try to sysout it, I'm getting an exception:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.maxActive}")
private String act;
```

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.maxActive' in string value "${spring.datasource.maxActive}`

Comment: install the actuator and check the value there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties` the default value is `100`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set spring.datasource.max-active in your application.properties or application.yaml to get the value in your bean class

Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html for common application.properties